# How does the holographic attachment work?

Tags: crysis-2

Some weapons have the holographic attachment, of which I haven't seen any practical use, yet.

How do they work?
Do I have to press a button, or do they have a situational effect?

Comment: Having not reached this stage I'm not sure, but I would imagine you press X to customise the weapon. Set the attachment, then press 2 to switch to it, and point and fire a hologram, which distracts enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to attachment ( "Use" I think, i have remapped it from F, afair correctly) and then activate it  with fire. Its very useful in MP when u can lure some enemies on your holo.
Visual effect on weapon, when you switch to holo module is - smallest crosshair and weapon pointed a bit up - then fire will launch hologram. Remember - you should switch back to firing mode before you can shoot with your wea